# Read certain lines php and txt

Tags: php, logging

Should I read a txt, up here we go, now how can I do so that it takes only the last 10 lines of writing? 
example 
if the txt I 
hello 1 
hello 2 
hello 3 
hello 4 
hello 5,

I would like to print to video only 
hello 4 
hello 5, 
how can I do this ?? 
Thanks in advance

This is code

```
$conta_td = 1;
$numero_td = 1;

echo " <table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\"> <tbody>";

$f = fopen("Func/form_ipn.log", "r");
while (!feof($f)) {
     $array = explode(",",fgets($f));
     $row = current( $array );

     if ($conta_td == 1){
         echo  "<tr>"; 
         echo"<td>$row </td>";
         if ($conta_td == $numero_td) {
             echo  "</tr>";
             $conta_td = 1;
         } else {
              $conta_td++;
         }
     }
     if ($conta_td!= 1) {
         while ($conta_td <= $numero_td) {
             echo  "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
             $conta_td++;
        }
    echo"</tr>";
    }
    echo  " </tbody></table>";
```

Comment: I would like a unicorn :D

Comment: You're not going to `fclose()` the file, do you? Also, learn the importance of indent.

Comment: No matter the fclose () function is at a later time, you can do what I asked?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to update your logic.

1. Load entire file into array
2. Determine "rows" in array
3. Run outputting cycle for last 10 elements in array

EDIT: Output cycle example

```
    function outputLastN($array, $howmany){
        if($howmany > 0 && count($array) > 0 && count($array) >= $howmany){
            echo "<table>";
            for($i=(count($array)-$howmany);$i<count($array);i++){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$array[$i]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I would also point some good practicies for you

1. Indent your code - it makes it more readable and easier to debug
2. Use functions (or maybe Object Oriented aproach) - it makes thinking about code easier as you are slicing code in smaller reusable pieces with their own responsibility for that particular task (e.g. outputting, file data loading,...)
3. Always try to split code logic and view. It makes thing more modular an maintainable